# Laravel : what is $query->time time unit?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, logging

According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database), it is possible to add a listener that will log all SQL queries, and log the query duration.

```
    public function boot()
{
    DB::listen(function ($query) {
        // $query->sql
        // $query->bindings
        $query->time
    });
}
```

My problem is that I don't know the unit of $query->time, and I can't find this information in the documentation. By reproducing the queries in the Mysql cli client it seems that the result returned are in deciseconds which seems very strange. Because of that I think that I misunderstood something and that measured time might not represent what I am expecting (the Mysql time to answer).

What is the unit of this element ? Is there a better Laravel documentation that could explain what is measured ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter you get there is of type

Illuminate/Database/Events/QueryExecuted

According to this

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Events/QueryExecuted.html

the time is "The number of milliseconds it took to execute the query."

Answer (score 0):

it's calculated using the `microtime` function, what you get is a milliseconds time value